# Using HttpServletRequest getPathInfo() with <a href="">

Tags: java, servlets, action

In my Java web application I am using the `HttpServletRequest` `getPathInfo()` method to get the path sent by a request to the Servlet.

My Servlet: `Controller` contains the following the following code:

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

         String action = request.getPathInfo();    

         RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;

         if(action.equals("/viewDetails"))
           {
              dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/viewDetails.jspx");
           }

       }
```

Here I am checking the what the action of the request is so that I can direct the user to the appropriate view.

Now in my `loginForm.jspx` I have a login form like this:

`<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/do/viewDetails">`

This proceeds to the controller with the action: `/viewDetails` that the controller recognizes.

In my web.xml I have mapped the `/do` pattern to link to the `Controller` servlet. So whenever the `/do` path is found, the request gets sent to the Controller which determines where to go (as seen in the processRequest method).

Now the problem I am having is that when I try to link to the controller the same way in a HTML `a` tag, it doesn't work, for example:

`<a href="http://localhost:8080/do/viewDetails">View all details</a>`

Is there a way I can perform the same action with `a href` as I did with `<form action...`?

**EDIT:**

Screenshot of the browser when I click the View All Details link:

[image]

Comment: is the url: http://localhost:8080/do/viewDetails reachable from your browser ? basically when you click the link it will try to reach this address, and if you handle this call to the servlet it should work.

Comment: @LeTex Yes the url is reachable from the browser however it doesn't actually open the `viewDetails.jspx`. The url is displayed properly in the browser address bar however... see edit

Comment: Perhaps the controller is expecting a POST request and ignoring the GET request that occurs when the user clicks a hyperlink.

Comment: What is a way around this?

Comment: You could have the anchor tag invoke javascript that posts a form. Or you could change your server-side code to treat GET requests the same as POSTs -- details would depend on the framework you are using. If it's just plain servlets, you could override doGet and have it delegate to doPost.